# Windows 10: Forced into Sleep Mode by unplugging a Headphone Jack

Tags: windows-10, audio, headphone-jack

This has been happening ever since I got this PC and Windows 10. I have headphones with a normal 3.5mm jack to plug into the front of my Tower.

Yet a lot of the time, unplugging them to use my normal speakers trips the system into Sleep mode.

The system is set to NEVER go to Sleep mode in the Settings "Power & Sleep" section.

But it also doesn't always happened. I was just playing Elder Scrolls Online with the headphones in. I unplugged them, Sleep Mode.

There is no real way to replicate it. It literally just happens randomly.

Using a video player. Sometimes if I have a video paused and the headphones are in, and unplug them to let speakers run it, it goes to sleep mode. Sometimes it doesn't.

It's all centered around this Headphone Jack, as far as I can tell, but I have no clue how to stop it from happening. It's just extremely annoying.

Answer (score 2):

In a property operating machine, the headphone jack will not interfere with the power system.

I suggest you document the issue as best you can and take the machine for service.

There is likely a false intermittent electrical path inside the machine that causes this (for example, headphone jack inside touches another wire or metal part of the power circuit).

Since this has been happening since new, something in the construction has likely caused this.